Looker Studio Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set (data comes from csv in google drive loaded to BQ)
source of data:
the original data that I have problems with resides on my google drive, in the form of a .csv file. It then gets uploaded to bigquery using the add > google drive, no issues here.
size:
the size of .csv file is over 107mb, this is why I can´t upload the csv directly to  looker studio, plus it's easier for me to get the csv data combined with other sources while working with it in BQ, which I can do without any issues.
what I can do:
In BQ: I can work with the data in BQ as usual, I can query/merged/combined the data in the .csv with other sources/tables through a BQ queries
in Looker Studio: I can add the datset as a custom Query from BQ or as view/table. I get no errors when getting the data in using the BQ connector in looker studio the problem starts when I need to use that dataset using a chart element or other dashboard element. no filters used.
where the problem appears:
Once I get a chart or any other data element in looker studio, I get an error that says that Looker Studio Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set, with some apparently random error code.
What I have tried:

since the error is common I went through this guide https://www.databloo.com/blog/looker-studio-cannot-connect-to-your-dataset/, no change.. the error continues no matter what.

I tried to explore the data (.csv file in question by itself) with looker studio starting from BQ, which starts a new looker studio file and that works, but I can´t reuse the source in any other looker studio file. now if I try to explore with looker studio the query in which I have 3 datasets combined (including the problem .csv) BQ does not give me the option to explore the data with looker studio. (option appears greyed out)


Current work around:
I loaded the problem .csv file to BQ and got a subset of the data in it exported to a google sheet (the original problem .csv has 2.5M rows, the subset I exported to google sheets has 20K), then I re-add the google sheet data with the subset to BQ so I can use the subset data to combine it in BQ with the other 2 sources I used in my query, then I can connect that Query to looker studio with no issues.
I just want to understand why looker can´t connect to the dataset if I use the csv loaded from google drive to bq, why aren´t there any errors when connecting to my full query to looker studio but the error only appears when I need to use the dataset resulting from my custom query? why is it that I can load a google sheet and I have no issues with that source in my custom query but I have issues if the data used in my custom query is sourced from the orignal .csv file stored in google drive?
please note that the csv, the google drive and permissions to access BQ they are all under my google account so I doubt this is a permissions issue.

It doesn't matter where the data originally came from once it's in BQ. So the question really is "Why can't Looker Studio connect to my BQ table", or rather "Why does Looker Studio show the error 'Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set' when connected to a BQ data source.
That question is tricky to answer. Looker Studio has become quite buggy recently. I have noticed that if a data source changes then this error can show up even though everything is set up correctly. Not exactly sure what triggers it.
The only solution is to remove the data source from Looker Studio and add it again.

hi @Sebastian
I got tired of doing that with the same end result.. I agree, once it's in BQ, the data be that the table added or a query that uses it, should be accesible through the connector in LDS.

I did isolated the problem to that .csv file because the other 2 sources in my query (a native table/view in BQ and a table from google sheets), they work fine, but once I bring the data from the csv it's over.
I thought the csv needed to be cleaned up and so I did, and then connected it again to BQ and then to my query but once I use the query with the 3 sources in LDS, including the cleaned up .csv i would get the error... completely clueless as to why this is happening., but thank you for checkiing in

Hmm. Can you share a CSV file that has that problem (stripped of all sensitive data ofc)?

Hi @Sebastian, the data is a simple csv with US tax rates, a 158mb file as per the last one that was given to me to work with. one work around I was able to find was that by changing the data credentials to viewers (from owner), the data started to show up in Looker DS

the problem of setting the datasource credentials to viewer implied that I´d have to somehow give access to the dataset either in BQ or Google drive to any user that may need access to the LDS dashboard, this poses other issues so I gave up on that workaround, besides, even after I gave access to a test user to the dataset in BQ and in GD, they still were not able to see the data shared through the dashboard so that was sort of a dead end unless I was the only one using the dashboard, which was not the case.

removing and adding the data might work in some escenarios where this error may appear as per serveral posts and google searches, but it was not my case. something in gdrive (likely a domain policy or setting) was making the data an external source after uploaded from gdrive to BQ, the bucket solution I was suggested made the data native to BQ and I think that made the difference... I could've also uploaded the data in parts but I didn´t wanted to go through the hassle of having to split up the data.

In consult with one of the data engineers, at the company I worked for, not being able to access the data stored in google drive from Looker Data Studio after it gets imported into BQ obeys to a google drive locked down implemented by the domain admins (I don´t have the details on what that setting is about), but one solution that was offered to me was to upload the csv to a gcc bucket and then use that as the source to import the csv to BQ, this will make the dataset as a native table (as opposed to an external table as it was when importing the file from Google drive) which in turn allowed me to bring any queries associated with that data into looker data studio while keeping access with my credentials for the datasource added in Looker Data studio. with that the problem was solved, hope this helps someone else.
